# How to align text to the left when inside a graphic?

Tags: plotting

I am using Show to display a set of lines. Now I am trying to label them inside the plot with P=0/0.25/0.5/0.75/0.9. However, as you can see from the attached plot, the text seems to center around 0.2, instead of being left aligned at 0.2. How can I get the 5 lines to be left aligned, and all starting at 0.2?

```
Show[plot, Graphics[{Text["--P=0", {0.2, 5.5}, 
TextStyle -> Directive[Bold, RGBColor["#123c69"], Medium]]}], 
Graphics[{Text["--P=0.25", {0.2, 5}, TextStyle -> Directive[Bold, 
RGBColor["#bab2b5"], Dashed, Medium]]}], Graphics[{Text["--P=0.5", {0.2, 4.5}, 
TextStyle -> Directive[Bold, RGBColor["#ac3b61"], DotDashed, Medium]]}], 
Graphics[{Text["--P=0.75", {0.2, 4}, TextStyle -> Directive[Bold, 
RGBColor["#edc7b7"], Medium]]}], Graphics[{Text["--P=0.9", {0.2, 3.5}, 
TextStyle -> Directive[Bold, RGBColor["#030a11"], Dotted, Medium]]}]]
```

[image]

To help you play with the code, I will attach the code to get the blue line, so you can run it with what you get for the blue one:

```
a = {{1.*10^-6, 0.}, {0.025001, 2.31442*10^-9}, {0.050001, 6198*10^-8},
{0.075001, 0.0000486898}, {0.100001, 0.00118944}, {0.125001, 
0.00795706}, {0.150001, 0.0279899}, {0.175001, 0.0683553}, {0.200001, 
0.133061}, {0.225001, 0.222841}, {0.250001, 0.33607}, {0.275001, 
0.469822}, {0.300001, 0.620694}, {0.325001, 0.785321}, {0.350001,
0.960656}, {0.375001, 1.14408}, {0.400001, 1.33343}, {0.425001, 
1.52695}, {0.450001, 1.72325}, {0.475001, 1.92128}, {0.500001, 2.1202},
{0.525001, 2.31938}, {0.550001, 2.51838}, {0.575001, 2.71684}, 
{0.600001, 2.91454}, {0.625001, 3.11129}, {0.650001, 3.30701}, 
{0.675001, 3.50161}, {0.700001, 3.69506}, {0.725001, 3.88736}, 
{0.750001, 4.07851}, {0.775001, 4.26853}, {0.800001, 4.45746}, 
{0.825001, 4.64532}, {0.850001, 4.83217}, {0.875001, 5.01803},
{0.900001, 5.20296}, {0.925001, 5.38699}, {0.950001, 5.57017},
{0.975001, 5.75254}, {1., 5.93414}}

plot = ListLinePlot[a, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {All, All}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Dashed, RGBColor["#123c69"]}, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {OverHat[T], \[Kappa]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 3-arg version of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) to specify the offset (I also changed the deprecated option [`TextStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextStyle) to the documented [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle)):

```
Show[
    plot,
    Graphics[{Text["--P=0", {0.2,5.5}, {-1,0},
        BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,RGBColor["#123c69"],Medium]]}],
    Graphics[{Text["--P=0.25", {0.2,5}, {-1,0},
        BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,RGBColor["#bab2b5"],Dashed,Medium]]}],
    Graphics[{Text["--P=0.5", {0.2,4.5}, {-1,0},
        BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,RGBColor["#ac3b61"],DotDashed,Medium]]}],
    Graphics[{Text["--P=0.75", {0.2,4}, {-1,0},
        BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,RGBColor["#edc7b7"],Medium]]}],
    Graphics[{Text["--P=0.9", {0.2,3.5}, {-1,0},
        BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,RGBColor["#030a11"],Dotted,Medium]]}]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach.

```
 opt = {Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"};

    legend = Column[{Style["--P=0", RGBColor["#123c69"], Evaluate@opt], 
    Style["\[LongDash]P=0.25", RGBColor["#bab2b5"], Evaluate@opt], 
    Style["\[Bullet]\[Dash]\[Bullet]P=0.5", RGBColor["#ac3b61"], 
     Evaluate@opt], 
    Style["\[LongDash]P=0.75", RGBColor["#edc7b7"], Evaluate@opt], 
    Style["\[Bullet]\[Bullet]\[Bullet]P=0.9", RGBColor["#030a11"], 
     Evaluate@opt]}, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {0, 0.5}];
ListLinePlot[a, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {All, All}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, RGBColor["#123c69"]}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {OverHat[T], \[Kappa]}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[legend, Scaled[{0.3, 0.7}]]]
```

[image]